# Selenium - Error: The expression is not a legal expression for xpath

Tags: java, selenium, xpath

In the site [https://javapapers.com/core-java/java-qr-code/] if I search for element with below xpath in browser

```
//div[@id='tutorial-body']/p/img
```

I am getting two matches, but if I use the same thing in selenium code

```
WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();
driver.get("https://javapapers.com/core-java/java-qr-code/");
Thread.sleep(2000);
WebElement qr_url = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[@id='tutorial-body']/p/img/"))
 String l =qr_url.getCssValue("src");
```

I am getting below error:

```
Exception in thread "main" org.openqa.selenium.InvalidSelectorException: Given xpath expression "//div[@id='tutorial-body']/p/img/" is invalid: SyntaxError: The expression is not a legal expression.
For documentation on this error, please visit: http://seleniumhq.org/exceptions/invalid_selector_exception.html
```

So what's wrong in my Xpath?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just remove extra slash in the end of expression:

```
"//div[@id='tutorial-body']/p/img/" --> "//div[@id='tutorial-body']/p/img"
```

Answer (score 1):

Also to aid you with xPath and avoid errors like this, you can Inspect and copy xPath using Chrome and enter the same value in selenium selector.[image]